# Post request for external api in appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

i try to send a post request to external server. But i am getting 500 error always.I tested in Postman using this URL and JSON object and It was worked.

> Request failed for https://demo.overconline.com/api/opportunities returned code 500. Truncated server response: {"message":"error.internalServerError","description":"Internal server error","fieldErrors":null} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 178, file "Code")

```
function createdOpportunity(){  
  var auth = getToken(); 
  var data = {
  "createdBy": "first-admin",
  "sequenceNumber": "",
  "indexKeyValue": "opportunity name",
  "stageId": "5b680dbcb5557900013686b8",
  "assignee": "None",
  "stageHistory": [
    {
      "stageId": "5b680dbcb5557900013686b8",
      "stageHistoryRecords": [
        {
          "addedDate": null,
          "removedDate": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "order": [],
  "permissionType": 2
};

  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  var webAppUrl="https://demo.overconline.com/api/opportunities";
  var header = {'contentType':'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer '+ auth };
  var options = { 'method':'POST','headers':header ,'payload':JSON.stringify(data)};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(webAppUrl, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(result);
  Logger.log('Permission type  '+response);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution for your issue, when you want to include the content type in the header, can you modify from ``'contentType'`` to ``'Content-Type'``? When you want to use ``contentType``, please include it in ``options``. The document is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params).

Comment: I changed 'contentType' to  'Content-Type'. But i get same error